# Print specific data into a web page using php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This is the result of Solr engine,I tried to decode it and convert it to an array
Now I have an array in this format and I want to display each value of each products on a web page 
Each products have a name, marque and categorie as features.
When I tried to loop trought it using foreach I got empty result.
and here is my array:

```
array(5) {
  ["_version_"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    float(1.6666659645964E+18)
    [1]=>
    float(1.6666659646163E+18)
    [2]=>
    float(1.6666659646173E+18)
    [3]=>
    float(1.6666659646184E+18)
    [4]=>
    float(1.6666659646194E+18)
    [5]=>
    float(1.6666659646205E+18)
    [6]=>
    float(1.6666659646236E+18)
  }
  ["categorie"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Bonbons"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Bonbons"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Bonbons"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Bonbons"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Bonbons"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Bonbons"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Bonbons"
    }
  }
  ["id"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "64678881-ed19-47cf-aaf5-877d7b45a6c7"
    [1]=>
    string(36) "4abb6b91-5e03-44ef-b728-a7f900e7a9f8"
    [2]=>
    string(36) "0d6380fd-b7b9-4447-ba7f-bbb032e4c5be"
    [3]=>
    string(36) "3e21b671-5d0b-4c01-8f8f-3b3f4c14ea4f"
    [4]=>
    string(36) "8865f4a6-f6b3-40f7-ad74-a15fdda62c4f"
    [5]=>
    string(36) "a4a11941-02fc-473b-8d42-87b890e2b141"
    [6]=>
    string(36) "92d8adde-1805-4bcc-8aaf-52aafad783c0"
  }
  ["marque"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "MENTOS"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "MENTOS"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "MENTOS"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Mentos"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "MENTOS"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "MENTOS"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "MENTOS"
    }
  }
  ["nom"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Bonbons parfums fruits MENTOS"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(21) "Bonbons menthe MENTOS"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(37) "Bonbons caramel/chocolat blanc MENTOS"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(31) "Bonbons caramel/chocolat MENTOS"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(28) "Bonbons menthe sucres MENTOS"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(31) "Bonbons framboise orange MENTOS"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(26) "Bonbons pomme verte MENTOS"
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my code using for loop :

```
<div class="row">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['execute'])) {
  $params=shell_exec('python Solr.py py2exe');
  $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $params);
  fclose($fp);
  $strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("results.json",JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  $data=json_decode($strJsonFileContents,true);
  print_r($data);
  for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    ?>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row product1">
      <h3><?php echo $data[4][$i]; ?></h3>
      <div class="image">
       <img src="images/" alt="" class="responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <span><strong>Marque: </strong><?php echo $data[3][$i]; ?></span><br>
        <span><strong>Categorie: </strong><?php echo $data[1][$i]; ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}}
?>
</div>
```

I edited the loop because I want that automatically so I replace 7 by count($data).now I get result but not all the result.it shows just 5 products but I have 7 products. 
$data is my array above.
and here is my edited code:

```
  for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($data);$i++){
    ?>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row product1">
      <h3><?php echo $data['nom'][$i][0]; ?></h3>
      <div class="image">
       <img src="images/" alt="" class="responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <span><strong>Marque: </strong><?php echo $data['marque'][$i][0]; ?></span><br>
        <span><strong>Categorie: </strong><?php echo $data['categorie'][$i][0]; ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

use this but replace arrrayname with the name of your array:

```
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
   echo "version > ".arrayname[0][$i].", categorize > ".arrayname[1][$i].", id > ".arrayname[2][$i].", marque > ".arrayname[3][$i].", nom > ".arrayname[4][$i];

}
```

this uses index to refer to the sub-array instead of the names

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still  get empty result

Comment: does the print_r function output anything??

Comment: yeah it output an array